# Any good Haxe IDE for linux / ubuntu?

Tags: linux, editor, haxe, openfl

I have find and tried different Haxe IDE in ubuntu and all have their own issues and dependencies even some have lost their support. Which is causing the IDE difficult to get ready for coding or development.

Currently using HIDE which is fair enough :s and get install in one command.

Is there any good working IDE for linux system ?

[update]

- Haxe studio has no autocomplete feature
- Sublime 2 bundle also do not support autocomplete or has one but don't show right properties
- Gedit2 plugin has bugs which says python not found
- Flashdevelope using wine opens a window which show list of flashdevelope extentions and do not go further then this screen.

Comment: While IDE's have their place, there is no replacement for simply coding with a good text-editor with a multi-document interface and good syntax-highlighting with an open terminal nearby. KDE's kate was/is one very capable editor which provides the ability to save collections of documents as a 'project'. gedit in gnome is OK as well. Don't forget 'vim' which is one of the most flexible editors on the planet that provides all the hooks needed to code, compile and test from within the editor (note it takes time to learn). Any terminal will do. I prefer KDE's konsole.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might want to look at this page:
https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/editors-and-ides.html

The options for Linux are:

- Visual Studio Code (With [Haxe extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vshaxe.haxe-extension-pack))
- IntelliJ IDEA (With [Haxe plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6873?pr=idea))
- Sublime Text (With [Haxe Bundle](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-sublime-bundle))
- VIM (With [Vaxe Plugin](https://github.com/jdonaldson/vaxe))
- [HaxeDevelop](https://haxedevelop.org) using [Wine](https://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8360)

Comment: You might want to add [Haxe Studio](http://www.haxestudio.com/) to the list. Also, there is some work on getting [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) functioning in Wine.

Comment: The IntelliJ haxe plugin now works on all JetBrains IDEs, that means their  limited but cheaper IDEs like WebStorm/PhpStorm can be used for Haxe development, too.

Comment: The IDEA community edition is free.

Comment: As i'm using my IDE for other stuff too, I use inteliJ idea community with the haxe plugin. setting up dependencies and changing targets is harder than FlashDevelop, and following tutorials is not that easy, but other than that it's a better IDE